# How to change a file extension of a file location

Tags: java

i have an application that a user uploads a file to,

but what i want is to detect the file extension of the uploaded file and if a doc file do something else do nothing

anyone have any ideas?

is there a way to change the file extension for example is a file was D:/test.doc to change to D:/test.pdf

i know this will not convert the file format, that will be done later

the file location changes every time etc so i just need a way to take the location, and change the file extension

code i have currently

```
File file = new File("oldname");

File file2 = new File("newname");
// Rename file (or directory)
boolean success = file.renameTo(file2);
if (!success)
{
// File was not successfully renamed
}
```

but this does not do it :(
The problem with this code is i must give the new file name, and i can not as it should be exactly the same as the old file name just with different extensions

EDIT 2

hopefully this will clear it up as the last question was a little confusing

basically, i have a program that converts an uploaded doc file to a pdf, but the location of the uploaded doc changes each time, as it creates a folder for each user

this is defined in the variable `String location`

what i want to do is take this variable `location` as this will end with a `.doc` and i want to change the `location` from `.doc` to `.pdf`

I have managed to find out the name of the file, without hte extension by using :

```
        String path = location;
        File f = new File(path);
        System.out.println(f.getName()); 
        String fName = f.getName();
        System.out.println(fName.substring(0, fName.lastIndexOf('.')));
```

but how can i find out the path before the name of file

EDIT for the last time i have found a solution

```
 System.out.println(path2.substring(0, path2.lastIndexOf('.')));
            newLocation = (path2.substring(0, path2.lastIndexOf('.')))+".pdf";
            System.out.println(newLocation);
```

Comment: fileName.endsWith(".doc")?

Comment: Oh ok, really didn't think it was that easy, Thanks !

Comment: is there a way to change the file extension for example is a file was D:/test.doc to change to D:/test.pdf

Comment: `File.rename()`? Don't you think you could find this by yourself? Google is your friend. The javadoc as well.

Comment: Ah sorry i should have stated, the filename and location changes everytime, and i just need to remove the .doc off the end and replace it with .pdf i have googled for this but it just shows how to do it if you know the output path

Comment: So, read the file name, replace its extension by .pdf, and rename the file. Have you read the String javadoc?

Comment: Yes, i have jsut been reading it, i have come up with the code above, but does not do the required task, how can ijust simply take the input location, and change the extension ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. It seems you want to take a *String* foo.doc and transform it into foo.pdf. Then read the *String* javadoc. length(), indexOf() and substring() should help you.

Comment: For the File parameter, did you use absolute path?

Comment: yes the file parameter is the absolute path e.g. `D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/Uploaded/null/HelloWorld.doc` i have edited the question to try and make it more clear, am reading up on google about it but its strange one

Answer (score 2):

You can simply check the extension by string matching, such as `endsWith()`.

To find out the path before the name of file, use lastIndexof("\") on the absolute path.

Comment: Answering a question with another question?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if he is asking something else.

Comment: Then that would be the appropriate use of a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 2):

If you need to check file extension of uploaded files i would suggest usage of magic numbers.

More details you can find [here](http://igormadjeric.blogspot.com/2012/07/checking-files-magic-numbers.html)

Checking of extension like .doc or .pdf does not mean that this file is word document or pdf document file.